# abort(TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined) React Native Metro Builder

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I am getting the following error in metro builder after running the app.

*RuntimeError: abort(TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
at process.abort (/Users/.../node_modules/metro-hermes-compiler/src/emhermesc.js:796:13)
at process.emit (node:events:365:28)
at emit (node:internal/process/promises:136:22)
at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:242:25)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:97:32)
Process terminated. Press  to close the window*

I have tried the following:

- Delete Podfile.lock
- Delete node_modules
- Clean xcode build folder
- react-native start --reset-cache
- watchman watch-del-all
- pod update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue. My problem was I tried to fix dependabot security issue  of `ws` which I resolve it to newer version. And I have this issue.

Now when I remove the resolution in `package.json` (I use yarn), it backs to work as usual now.

Comment: Yes that library was actually the issue I had to remove it from my project to get it to work. Have you managed getting it to work with the library?

Comment: Sadly, not yet.